# Was the "Tall Man" who abducted David the mother?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-tall-man

In *[The Tall Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1658837/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* from 2012, there is a legendary "Tall Man" who takes children. The character of Julia Denning has her child, David, taken while she sleeps, and she goes on a prolonged chase of the blackclad figure.

> Was this supposed to be Mrs. Johnson, David's actual mother?

I feel like there ought to be some evidence to be drawn from the film, possibly scenes where the van or the dog are associated with said person, but I didn't see it on the first viewing, and I couldn't convince my wife of a second.